# Erlang, Rebar and organization of programs with multiple applications

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar

I'm embarking on a large project with multiple applications; wondering how to best organize it under Rebar. My current thinking below. Is this a satisfactory solution or is there a better scheme?

```
project_root_dir
   apps 
      application1 
      application2
      ...       
   deps
      dep1
      dep2
      ...
   rebar.config
```

Where rebar.config looks like:

```
{sub_dirs, ["apps/application1",
            "apps/application2",
            ...
           ]}.

{lib_dirs, ["deps"]}.
{deps, [dep1,
        dep2,
        ...
        ]}.
```

Many thanks for your guidance.

LRP

Comment: There is no necessity in `lib_dirs` option in this configuration.

Comment: thats how most of the projects are lined up. you don't need `lib_dirs`. take a look @ basho github projects for inspiration. You should also add a release via reltool `rel/files, rel/vars.config, rel/reltoo.config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to keep each application in `apps` in a separate repository and then you can have an `assembling` repository which runs the release. `Riak` is distributed like this.